# Firedac data traffic volumes

Tags: delphi, firedac

How can I get the size of the data returned from the database by a TFDConnection?  i.e. Network traffic in bytes.

I want a driver agnostic solution as the app uses several data sources.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but why do you need that?

Comment: For managing, monitoring and performance tuning cloud applications